# Need help on start using purescript on NixOS

Tags: purescript, nix, nixos

I am trying to setup `hello world` project with `purescript` on `NixOs` and have couple questions,

1. [Official](http://www.purescript.org/) `purescript` website recommend installation via `npm` but there is no `nixos.nodePackages.purescript`, instead there are at least 2 variants I found in `nixpkgs`

   - nixos.purescript
   - nixos.haskellPackages.purescript

**What are the different?**

2. Official site recommend `pulp` and `bower` via `npm` but only `nodePackages.bower` is avaliable and there is undocumented `psc-package`.

**What should be the `nix` way to handle purescript packages?**

3. The sample code on official site (see `hello.purs` bellow) doesn't even compile,

with these error.

```
$ purs compile hello.purs

Error found:
at hello.purs line 1, column 1 - line 1, column 1

Unable to parse module:
unexpected "import"
expecting "module"
```

I add `module Hello` to code but still failed.

```
$ purs compile hello.purs 
Error 1 of 2:

  in module Hello
  at hello.purs line 2, column 1 - line 2, column 15

    Module Prelude was not found.
    Make sure the source file exists, and that it has been provided as an input to psc.


  See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/ModuleNotFound.md for more information,
  or to contribute content related to this error.

Error 2 of 2:

  in module Hello
  at hello.purs line 3, column 1 - line 3, column 39

    Module Control.Monad.Eff.Console was not found.
    Make sure the source file exists, and that it has been provided as an input to psc.


  See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/ModuleNotFound.md for more information,
  or to contribute content related to this error.
```

**How the correct workflow should be?**

---

The goal is to have minimal example project with a single `hello.purs` 
running in web browser.

This is `hello.purs`

```
module Hello where
import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (log)

greet :: String -> String
greet name = "Hello, " <> name <> "!"

main = log (greet "World")
```

It would be really helpful if you can also provide `shell.nix` for `nix-shell` or `default.nix` for `nix-build`.

Found this 2 years old [guild](https://pr06lefs.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/get-started-with-purescript-on-nixos/), I am trying it but I still not have answer to all of my questions.

Comment: Justin Woo's [`easy-purescript-nix`](https://github.com/justinwoo/easy-purescript-nix) project may be helpful too, here's [his announcement](https://discourse.purescript.org/t/easy-purescript-with-nix/496) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. nixos.purescript is just the static executables for nixos.haskellPackages.purescript; this skips building/installing PureScript as a Haskell library
2. You can install Pulp via `npm install pulp` - the binary will be installed to `node_modules/.bin/pulp`
3. The sample code doesn't compile because you haven't downloaded the dependencies via Bower. You can install them via `bower install purescript-prelude purescript-console`.

But `node_modules/.bin/pulp init` will give you a Bower file and you can run `bower install` to give you a basic project. You can then do `node_modules/.bin/pulp run` to execute it using node.js, but you'll probably want `pulp browserify --to example.js` to get a file you can put in a `<script>` tag in HTML.

Comment: Hi @Brian - Thanks for your answer! I'm NixOS newbie (just downloaded an image ;-)), so I want to add some more questions: What do you think about this project: https://github.com/ElvishJerricco/nix-purescriptPackages ? I've got another more general question: Do you think that coding in Purescript  experience on NixOS (as you described it above) has any advantages over development on other OS'es?

Comment: NixOS doesn't have a lot of PureScript support so you won't get a huge amount of benefits if you're just working with PureScript libraries and tools. I could be a lot better, but we need to spend the time to write the Nix code to support PureScript well. I haven't used it, but purescriptPackages is the right direction :)